# Can anyone guess what protocol these packets belong to?

Tags: mobile, networking, protocols

We see these packets being injected in an FTP-DTP channel during a downlink file transfer on Telstra's NEXTG mobile network. We are not sure if these are network level packets, a problem with our 3G modem (HC25 based) or something like our firewall injecting in the stream.

Using a tool we noticed that the PPP framing fails with protocol length errors, so they are mostly likely mobile network packets.

I am hoping someone here can identify the signature of the packets so that I can chase this up with the appropriate vendor.

There is definitely a format to these packets: -

Packet1:
00 00 00 24 c4 b8 7b 1a 00 90 7f 43 0f a1 08 00 45 00 01 10 f4 4e 00 00 40 06 2f 13 cb 7a 9d e9 7b d0 71 52 7a ed 04 06 8c 61 5d a9 01 f7 0c eb 50 10 ff ff 58 b9 00 00

Packet2:
00 00 00 24 c4 b8 7b 1a 00 90 7f 43 0f a1 08 00 45 00 00 ff 6b 50 00 00 40 06 b8 22 cb 7a 9d e9 7b d0 71 52 7a ed 04 06 8c 61 7b 82 01 f7 0c eb 50 10 ff ff a3 79 00 00

Packet3:
00 00 00 24 c4 b8 7b 1a 00 90 7f 43 0f a1 08 00 45 00 02 20 5b 50 00 00 40 06 c7 01 cb 7a 9d e9 7b d0 71 52 7a ed 04 06 8c 61 7c 59 01 f7 0c eb 50 10 ff ff e2 5d 00 00

Packet4:
00 00 00 24 c4 b8 7b 1a 00 90 7f 43 0f a1 08 00 45 00 01 38 d8 52 00 00 40 06 4a e7 cb 7a 9d e9 7b d0 71 52 7a ed 04 06 8c 62 42 f9 01 f7 0c eb 50 10 ff ff 20 91 00 00

Packet5:
00 00 00 24 c4 b8 7b 1a 00 90 7f 43 0f a1 08 00 45 00 00 d0 4d 58 00 00 40 06 d6 49 cb 7a 9d e9 7b d0 71 52 7a ee 04 08 4b fb 0b 8f 03 5d 51 1a 50 10 ff ff e9 88 00 00

Comment: As near as I can tell they belong to "$Ä¸{". HTH.

Comment: Yeah, good luck with that mate.

Comment: You did say guess. Is it HDLC?  actually I have no idea.

Comment: You'll probably find more people with experience in packet analysis on ServerFault.com.

Comment: Thanks Ash, I posted a duplicate on serverfault.com.

Comment: Cross post: http://serverfault.com/questions/89652/can-anyone-guess-what-protocol-these-packets-belong-to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These look like ordinary TCP packets but with two extra 00 bytes tagged on at the front.  Not sure why that would happen, but they appear to be from 00-90-7f-43-0f-a1 (Watchguard) to 00-24-c4-b8-7b-1a (Cisco).

IP header is 45 00 01 10 f4 4e 00 00 40 06 2f 13 cb 7a 9d e9 7b d0 71 52

TCP header is 7a ed 04 06 8c 61 5d a9 01 f7 0c eb 50 10 ff ff 58 b9 00 00

So you can get the rest of the details from there.

Answer (score 6):

I converted your packet trace snippet into a format understood by [text2pcap](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/text2pcap.html) so I could convert them into the pcap format for viewing in [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) (a very handy packet capture and analysis tool):

Looks like some sort of IPv4 multicast traffic at a very rough guess. Here's what I got from the first packet (rest came up as malformed):

```
No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Info
      1 0.000000    7b:1a:00:90:7f:43     00:00:00_24:c4:b8     0x0fa1   Ethernet II

Frame 1 (31 bytes on wire, 31 bytes captured)
    Arrival Time: Dec  1, 2009 00:33:05.000000000
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 1
    Frame Length: 31 bytes
    Capture Length: 31 bytes
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Protocols in frame: eth:data]
Ethernet II, Src: 7b:1a:00:90:7f:43 (7b:1a:00:90:7f:43), Dst: 00:00:00_24:c4:b8 (00:00:00:24:c4:b8)
    Destination: 00:00:00_24:c4:b8 (00:00:00:24:c4:b8)
        Address: 00:00:00_24:c4:b8 (00:00:00:24:c4:b8)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
    Source: 7b:1a:00:90:7f:43 (7b:1a:00:90:7f:43)
        Address: 7b:1a:00:90:7f:43 (7b:1a:00:90:7f:43)
        .... ...1 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Group address (multicast/broadcast)
        .... ..1. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Locally administered address (this is NOT the factory default)
    Type: Unknown (0x0fa1)
Data (17 bytes)

0000  08 00 45 00 01 10 f4 4e 00 00 40 06 2f 13 cb 7a   ..E....N..@./..z
0010  9d                                                .
    Data: 080045000110F44E000040062F13CB7A9D
```

Answer (score 2):

00:24:c4 is a NIC from Cisco and 00:90:7F is a NIC from WatchGuard.

From the [IEEE OUI Registry](http://standards.ieee.org/regauth/oui/oui.txt).

How much help that might be ... don't know.  Might therefore be an attempted VPN connection.

Answer (score 0):

As already decoded by others:

- first 6+6+2 bytes identifying NIC and Ethernet II.
- bytes 0x0800 EtherType telling that it is IP. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherType
- next octet starting with nibble "4" is IPv4
- etc.